# how useful short workout?

Tags: workout-routines, workout, high-intensity, timing

Lately I have read many articles, all of which explain that a short workout is good and even better than a longer workout. For example:

[IS A SHORT BUT INTENSE WORKOUT BEST?](http://www.mensfitness.com/training/is-a-short-but-intense-workout-best)

[1 Minute of All-Out Exercise May Have Benefits of 45 Minutes of Moderate Exertion](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2016/04/27/1-minute-of-all-out-exercise-may-equal-45-minutes-of-moderate-exertion/?_r=0)

Is it true? Is it better to exercise several minutes than 1 hour?

If yes, how long it should be? 1, 10, 15 min?

Comment: Check out the Q&A in the "high-intensity" tag, see http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-intensity?sort=votes&pageSize=30

Comment: What is the/your goal behind this? Is this for workouts as a health necessity?

Comment: @JJosaur, yes, just for health

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The articles are probably based on variations of Tabata style training, a form of HIIT, which has been studied and does indeed show better overall improvements in both aerobic and anaerobic capacities.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8897392

High intensity interval training (HIIT) is based on short periods of maximum effort, usually 30 seconds to 1 minute, followed by 1 - 2 minutes rest, repeatedly performed for 'sets'. The type of exercise and the time allowed is interchangeable, as long as it's a sensible way to put in maximum effort. Running sprints or cycling machines with high resistance are favourites. Here's an inspiring video of former Olympic weightlifter Dmitry Klokov performing a Tabata with a barbell, and *ridiculous* amounts of weight:

https://youtu.be/2zIp1zYTTTg

How many sets you do is down to your current level of fitness. Four or five rounds is plenty for a routine session. Stay safe when performing an intense exercise; it goes without saying you should pick one you're already well practiced in.